# I can't choose Freestyle color in one file

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, freestyle

I have been using it for a while, it's even activated on my default settings, today i got a problem while creating a new file/model, it shows an orange like freestyle color, i can't even change it, i checked and everything is ok, i append it to other files or new files and it works nice, why it doesn't work in the main file? Sometimes i misspress some keys, maybe i pressed something that i didn't have to.

[image]
https://s19.postimg.org/56olmn64j/Outlines.png

I know i have a simple solution (Append it to a new file), but i would like to know what is this issue